# how to restrict student and teacher from accessing eachothers pages by directly entering url in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, authorization, zend-framework2

`localhost.test/teacher/marklist` - `teacher` is controller and marklist is view page.

A `student` logging in and typing the above `url` will display the page.
How to prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to prevent it but the suggested way in Zend is to use Zend_Acl and make roles: Student, Teacher and resources.

You can read more about **Zend Access Control List** [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.html).

From [Zend Page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.introduction.html):

> Zend_Acl provides a lightweight and flexible access control list (ACL) implementation for privileges management. In general, an application may utilize such ACL's to control access to certain protected objects by other requesting objects.
>
> For the purposes of this documentation:
>
> - a resource is an object to which access is controlled.
> - a role is an object that may request access to a Resource

So basicly you need to make:

1. Autentication - simple login form and keeping data in session
2. Authorization - **Zend_Acl** may be useful.